# What is the equivalent to “serverceipoptin /enable” in Windows Server 2019 Server Core?

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-server-core

I am trying to configure my servers to automatically send data related to Microsoft Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP) - in other words, send software quality telemetry to Microsoft. On previous versions of Windows Server (in a Server Core installation), I would run:

```
serverceipoptin /enable
```

However, it seems that serverceipoptin is not present on Windows Server 2019 (Server Core installation). What would be the supported, recommended command to put the equivalent configuration in place?

These systems are not joined to a domain and have no graphical user interface, so valid answers must present a cmd.exe command or PowerShell command. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After using Sysinternals Process Monitor to watch what ServerCeipOptin.exe does on Windows Server 2012 R2, I was able to observe that it writes one registry value when run with the /enable switch. On Windows Server 2019, since ServerCeipOptin.exe is missing, the following command:

```
ServerCeipOptin.exe /enable
```

Can be approximated by running the following equivalent command:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient\Windows" /v "CEIPEnable" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

---

For those more interested in the **/disable** switch, the equivalent command is:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient\Windows" /v "CEIPEnable" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```